# SQL - Updating rows with individual rows from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to insert data to each appropriate row with matching ID's and DayNumber's from Table1 called #Test to Table2 called #BlueTable

I'm working with this

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
            ID int,
            DayNumber  nvarchar(1), 
            MNumber nvarchar(2),
            QLetter nvarchar(1),
            Comments    nvarchar(60)
        )

insert into #Test(ID,DayNumber,MNumber,QLetter,Comments) 
  values(55,'1','2','A','000000'),
    (55,'5','2','A','111111'),
    (66,'7','2','A','222222'),
    (66,'7','2','B','333333')

  CREATE TABLE #BlueTable (
            ID nvarchar(40),
            DayNumber  nvarchar(1),
            BL_MN   nvarchar(2),
            BL_QL   nvarchar(1),
            BL_CM   nvarchar(60),
            BL_MN2  nvarchar(2),
            BL_QL2  nvarchar(1),
            BL_CM2  nvarchar(60)
        )

 declare @i int=1

while (@i <=7)
begin
   insert into #BlueTable(ID,DayNumber) 
  values(55,@i),
     (66,@i)

   set @i=@i+1
end

declare @loop int=1,
    @loopWord nvarchar(MAX)=''

   while(@loop<=2)-- HOW UPDATE IS RAN
  begin
       exec('update #BlueTable set BL_MN'+@loopWord+'=#Test.MNumber,BL_QL'+@loopWord+'=#Test.QLetter,BL_CM'+@loopWord+'=#Test.Comments from #Test
 where #BlueTable.ID=#Test.ID and #BlueTable.DayNumber = #Test.DayNumber')

    set @loop =@loop+1
    set @loopWord=@loop
 end


select * from #Test
select * from #BlueTable order by ID
drop table #Test
drop table #BlueTable
```

I was expecting at least some null values but it seems to overwrite previous updates and fills in with new data. This was how I Updated it

The output i've been trying to get should look like this when using (select * from #BlueTable where BL_CM is not null order by ID): **What I want**

```
ID  | DayNumber | BL_MN | BL_QL |    BL_CM     | BL_MN2 | BL_QL2 | BL_CM2 |
55       1          2       A       000000        null     null     null
55       5          2       A       111111        null     null     null
66       7          2       A       222222         2        B      333333
```

Instead I get something that looks like this: **What I am getting**

```
 ID  | DayNumber | BL_MN | BL_QL |    BL_CM     | BL_MN2 | BL_QL2 | BL_CM2 |
 55      1          2        A        000000        2         A     000000
 55      5          2        A        111111        2         A     111111
 66      7          2        A        222222        2         A     222222
```

Please help :(

Comment: Hi, I can not see when you run the update query. But the result shows that you run the update query twice.

Comment: @BurakAltin fixed now it can be ran with copy and paste

Comment: @amphetamachine Microsoft SQL-server and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this query. I suggest you to get your desired result first. Then insert in second table.

```
insert into #BlueTable
select
    ID, DayNumber, max(case when rn = 1 then MNumber end)
    , max(case when rn = 1 then QLetter end)
    , max(case when rn = 1 then Comments end)
    , max(case when rn = 2 then MNumber end)
    , max(case when rn = 2 then QLetter end)
    , max(case when rn = 2 then Comments end)
from (
    select
        *, rn = row_number() over (partition by ID, DayNumber order by MNumber, QLetter)
    from 
        #Test
) t
group by ID, DayNumber
```

Comment: This is very cleaver. I'm just going to play around with this to see if this can handle 6 more columns of 3 to see how insane this can get.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `INNER JOIN` update should work for your scenario. An example of how to update columns from table to another below.

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.BL_CM2 = T2.BL_CM2, T1.BL_QL2 = T2.BL_QL2, ... more columns
FROM #Test T1
INNER JOIN #BlueTable T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.DAYNUMBER = T2.DAYNUMBER
```

**EDIT**:

I think what you are looking is something like below:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.BL_MN = T2.MNumber, T1.BL_QL = T2.QLetter, T1.BL_CM = T2.Comments, 
    T1.BL_MN2 = T3.MNumber, T1.BL_QL2 = T3.QLetter, T1.BL_CM2 = T3.Comments
FROM #BlueTable T1
LEFT JOIN #Test T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.DAYNUMBER = T2.DAYNUMBER AND T2.QLetter = 'A'
LEFT JOIN #Test T3
ON T1.ID = T3.ID AND T1.DAYNUMBER = T3.DAYNUMBER AND T3.QLetter = 'B'
```

Comment: @Sleepyfalcon the join condition is unique, at least with your test data, what is the issue that you are actually encountering here? Just from updating one table with data from another table - the query is fine - your `#BlueTable` will have nulls where join didn't match.

Comment: This method rewrites over previous updates. Easiest example is where the 'B' question value is overwritten with 'A' question With ID of 66

Comment: @Sleepyfalcon Oh right, I think I get you, so that is happening because you have two ID's of 66 and DayNumber 7 which both match `JOIN` condition, but the QLetter is different. Are you looking to make that work as well or is this test data issue? Essentially, what I am asking - is the `#Test` table unique by a combination of ID, DayNumber and QLetter or just ID and DayNumber

Comment: In a way im trying to get it so that IF that the first BL_NM, BL_QL, and BL_CM is filled with a different answer it would move over to the next column set of three columns  and fill it in with the new answers. Example I have above in my original question.

Comment: @Sleepyfalcon Yep I get you now - check my updated answer

Comment: It's closer but it has a Case where it's first come. Meaning that if B comes after A then it would put the "B" question in front of the "A" Question. AKA The Example shown would switch the (2,B,222222) with (2,A,333333)

Comment: @Sleepyfalcon that is correct, however, you would not be able impose order here unless you had some column to order by. I don't think it is possible to achieve without extra data indicating the order that it was written.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, You will never get this result because when you insert the records 
    into #Test table, you duplicated ID=66, DayNumber=7.

> ```
> ID  | DayNumber | BL_MN | BL_QL |    BL_CM     | BL_MN2 | BL_QL2 | BL_CM2 |
> 55      1          2        A        000000        2         A     000000
> 55      5          2        A        111111        2         A     111111
> 66      7          2        A        222222        2         A     222222
> ```

So, probably, the result may looks like this. If you do not want to see this 
   result, you could filter by  **QLetter ='A'**  only.

> ```
> ID  | DayNumber | BL_MN | BL_QL |    BL_CM     | BL_MN2 | BL_QL2 | BL_CM2 |
> 55      1          2        A        000000        2         A     000000
> 55      5          2        A        111111        2         A     111111
> 66      7          2        A        222222        2         A     222222
> 66      7          2        B        333333        2         B     333333
> ```

So, I would like to recommend to use this query just after populate data and 
   before do any update. For this update, you actually no need SQL Procedure. 
   Just convert this SELECT query into update. Hope, this will helps.

```
    SELECT 
       B.ID, 
       B.DayNumber, 
       T.MNumber AS BL_MN_1, 
       T.QLetter AS BL_QL_1, 
       T.Comments AS BL_CM_1,
       T.MNumber AS BL_MN_2, 
       T.QLetter AS BL_QL_2, 
       T.Comments AS BL_CM_2
    FROM #BlueTable AS B
    INNER JOIN #Test T ON T.ID = B.ID AND T.DayNumber = B.DayNumber
```

**OR**

```
    SELECT 
       B.ID, 
       B.DayNumber, 
       T.MNumber AS BL_MN_1, 
       T.QLetter AS BL_QL_1, 
       T.Comments AS BL_CM_1,
       T.MNumber AS BL_MN_2, 
       T.QLetter AS BL_QL_2, 
       T.Comments AS BL_CM_2
    FROM #BlueTable AS B
    INNER JOIN #Test T ON T.ID = B.ID AND T.DayNumber = B.DayNumber AND T.QLetter = 'A'
```

Actually, I am wondering, why are you trying to update #BlueTable with same 
   informations. For this case, it would work. If you tell me specific 
   requirement, that could change this solution as well. Good luck.

Comment: The Requirements are coming from one giant table in one Database with a bunch of clustered information, that will fillter out the info that i need into a temp table, and then is stored into another Database. This example is easier to grasp compared to the real ball ache.